# Regarding Storing Structure in file using read and write

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, struct

I need to make the data in the structure as persistent i.e wanted to store it in a file and need to read that character by character...For this i had written the below code...the below code is not working it is unable to write the structure into the file(character by character)...**I needed that character by character**

```
struct x *x1=(struct x*)malloc(sizeof(struct x));
x1->y=29;
x1->c='A';
char *x2=(char *)malloc(sizeof(struct x));
char *s=(char *)malloc(sizeof(struct x));
for(i=0;i<sizeof(struct x);i++)
{
    *(x2+i)=*((char *)x1+i);
}
fd=open("rohit",O_RDWR); 
num1=write(fd,x2,sizeof(struct x));
num2=read(fd,s,sizeof(struct x));
for(i=0;i<sizeof(struct x);i++)
     printf(" %d ",*(s+i));
```

I can use fread & fwrite...but i wanted to do that character by character...so i am using read & write(they are direct system calls rite)...i am unable to write into it my write function is showing error i.e it is returning -1...Is there anything wrong in the above code...

Comment: If a system call (like `read` or `write`) returns `-1` that means something is wrong. You can find out _what_ is wrong by checking [`errno`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno).

Comment: I am getting bad file descriptor error...what does it mean? @JoachimPileborg

Comment: Please show how your open the file.

Comment: fd=open("rohit",O_CREAT,(mode_t)0600);

Comment: You have not opened your file for writing. Try adding O_RDWR. Also, be sure to check all return values from your functions...

Comment: Thanx @ElPaco... open("/home/associatedean/workspace/read_write/data/rohit",O_CREAT,(mode_t)0600);                                                                                                           fd=open("/home/associatedean/workspace/read_write/data/rohit",O_RDWR);                                                                         **Now it is showing No such file or directory ...although it is getting created there**

Comment: You probably want "O_CREATE | O_RDWR" so it's created if it's not present. Do you get a file descriptor?

Comment: After changing the code...my write is working fine ...NO errors are showing...but the read is returning 0 although write is returning 8...in the above code....Thanx for helping out @ElPaco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two functions you can use if you want:

```
int store(char * filename, void * ptr, size_t size)
{
  int fd, n;

  fd = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644);
  if (fd < 0)
    return -1;

  n = write(fd, (unsigned char *)ptr, size);
  if (n != size)
    return -1;

  close(fd);
  return 0;
}

int restore(char * filename, void * ptr, size_t size)
{
  int fd, n;

  fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY, 0644);
  if (fd < 0)
    return -1;

  n = read(fd, (unsigned char *)ptr, size);
  if (n != size)
    return -1;

  close(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you tagged this as C++, I'll give you the C++ answer.

From what I can tell from your code you have a `struct x1` such that

```
 struct { 
     int  y;
     char c;
 };
```

And you wish to serialise it's state to and from disk, to do this we need to create some stream insertion and stream extraction opterators;

```
//insertions
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const x& x1) {
     return os << x1.y << '\t' << x1.c;
}
//extration
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, x& x1) {
     return is >> x1.y >> x1.c;
}
```

Now to serailise the state of an `x` we can do the following

```
x x1 { 29, 'A' };
std::ofstream file("rohit");
file << x1;
```

And to deserialise

```
x x1;
std::ifstream file("rohit");
file >> x1;
```

Comment: The problem i am facing is....No such file or directory error...although the file is there...                                                         fd=creat("rohit",0666);...fd=open("rohit",O_RDWR);..............when i am writing using write system call it is showing error No such file or directory

Comment: Now no errors in the code specified by me...but although the write function is returning 8..the read function unable to read and is returning 0....why is that?

Comment: Because you don't reset the file pointer between the write and the read (after the write it points to the end of the file). The doctor recommends lseek.